# inserting into array's at specific point

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion

I am trying to insert elements to the front and back of an array to sort of simulate a priority list, where the task entered with a high priority gets put at the top but the task with a low priority at the bottom. my problem is that the code works for inserting at the top or the bottom but does not show the middle values that were entered. am i overwriting the values somewhere ??

i'm limted to the header files i can use. i would have done this whole thing with vectors otherwise

thanks for any help given.

below is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void storeinfo() ;
void showinfo() ;
void menu() ;
void deleteinfo() ;
void inserttask() ;
void displayallinfo() ;
void selectionSort() ;
void inserttop(string) ;
void insertbottom(string) ;
int linsearch(string val) ;


class user 
{
    string firstname, lastname, currentteam, position, status ;
    int age ;
public:
    user() {};
    user(string fname, string lname, string cteam, string pos, string stat, int age) 
    {
        setFirstName(fname);
        setLastName(lname);
        setCurrentTeam(cteam);
        setPosition(pos);
        setStatus(stat);
        setAge(age);
    } ;

    void setFirstName(string fname)
        {firstname = fname;}
    void setLastName(string lname)
        {lastname = lname;}
    void setCurrentTeam(string cteam)
        {currentteam = cteam;}
    void setPosition(string pos)
        {position = pos;}
    void setStatus(string stat)
        {status = stat;}
    void setAge(int _age)
        {age = _age;}

    string getFirstName()
        {return firstname ;}
    string getLastName()
        {return lastname ;}
    string getCurrentTeam()
        {return currentteam ;}
    string getPosition()
        {return position ;}
    string getStatus()
        {return status ;}
    int getAge()
        {return age ;}
};

user player[20] ;
int arrlength = 3 ;
string list[6] ;
int listlength = 6;

int main()
{
    menu() ;

    cin.get() ;
    return 0 ;
}

void storeinfo()
{
    string firstname ;
    string lastname ;
    string currentteam ;
    string position;
    string status ;
    int age ;

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n\n Enter First Name : " ; 
        cin >> firstname ;
        player[i].setFirstName(firstname) ;
        cout << "Enter Last Name : " ; 
        cin >> lastname ;
        player[i].setLastName(lastname) ;
        cout << "Enter Player's Age : " ; 
        cin >> age;
        player[i].setAge(age) ;
        cout << "Enter Current Team : " ; 
        cin >> currentteam ;
        player[i].setCurrentTeam(currentteam) ;
        cout << "Enter Position : " ; 
        cin >> position ;
        player[i].setPosition(position) ;
        cout << "Enter Status : " ; 
        cin >> status ;
        player[i].setStatus(status) ;

        cout << "\n\n\n" ;
    }

    /*cout << string(50, '\n');*/

    menu() ;

}

void showinfo()
{
    string search;
    int found ;


    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

    found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==-1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n First Name : " << player[found].getFirstName() << "\n" << "Last Name : " << player[found].getLastName() <<
            "\n" << "Age : " << player[found].getAge() << "\n" << "Current Team : " << player[found].getCurrentTeam() << 
            "\n" << "Position : " << player[found].getPosition() << "\n" << "Status :  " << player[found].getStatus()  << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;

}

void deleteinfo()
{
    int arrlength = 3 ;
    string search ;
    int found ;

    cout << "\n Delete A Player's Information \n\n" ;
    cout << "Please Enter The Player's Last Name : " ;
    cin >> search ;

        found=linsearch(search);

    if (found==-1)
    {
        cout << "\n There is no player called " << search ;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=found + 1; i < arrlength; ++i)
        {
            player[i-1].setFirstName(player[i].getFirstName()) ;
            player[i-1].setLastName(player[i].getLastName()) ;
            player[i-1].setAge(player[i].getAge()) ;
            player[i-1].setCurrentTeam(player[i].getCurrentTeam()) ;
            player[i-1].setPosition(player[i].getPosition()) ;
            player[i-1].setStatus(player[i].getStatus()) ;
        }

        --arrlength ;

        cout << "\n Player has been deleted." ;

        player[arrlength].setAge(0) ;
        player[arrlength].setCurrentTeam("") ;
        player[arrlength].setFirstName("") ;
        player[arrlength].setLastName("") ;
        player[arrlength].setPosition("") ;
        player[arrlength].setStatus("");
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}

void displayallinfo()
{

    for (int index = 0; index < arrlength -1; index++) // sorting algorithm,
        {
            if (player[index].getAge() > player[index+1].getAge())
            {
                user temp; // create temporary user
                temp = player[index]; // position is set to temp
                player[index] =  player[index+1]; // swap takes place
                player[index+1] =  temp; // new value is what was stored in temp
            }
        }


    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) //display all
    {
        cout << "\nFirst Name : " << player[i].getFirstName() << "\n" << "Last Name : " << player[i].getLastName() <<
            "\n" << "Age : " << player[i].getAge() << "\n" << "Current Team : " << player[i].getCurrentTeam() << 
            "\n" << "Position : " << player[i].getPosition() << "\n" << "Status :  " << player[i].getStatus()  << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}

void inserttask()
{
    string task ;
    string priority ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter name of task to be performed : " ;
        cin >> task ;

        cout << "\nEnter priority rating : " ;
        cout << "\nHigh or Low" ;
        cin >> priority ;
            if (priority == "High" | priority == "high")
            {
                inserttop(task) ;
            }
            else if(priority =="Low" | priority =="low")
            {
                insertbottom(task) ;
            }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        cout << list[j] ;
    }

    cin.get() ;

    menu() ;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\n MENU" << "\n" ;
    cout << "\n A. Store Player Information" ;
    cout << "\n B. Show Player Informaton" ;
    cout << "\n C. Delete Player Information" ;
    cout << "\n D. Display All Players Sorted By Age";
    cout << "\n E. Insert tasks by priority" ;
    cout << "\n Z. Exit \n\n" ;

    string x =  "";
    cin >> x ;

    if (x=="a" | x=="A")
    { 
        storeinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="b" | x=="B")
    {
        showinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="c" | x=="C")
    {
        deleteinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="d" | x=="D")
    {
        displayallinfo() ;
    }
    else if (x=="e" | x=="E")
    {
        inserttask() ;
    }
    else if (x=="z" | x=="Z")
    {
        exit(0) ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Choice" ;
        menu() ;
    }
}

int linsearch(string val)
{
    for (int j=0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if  (player[j].getLastName()==val)
         return j ;         
    }
        return -1 ;
}

void inserttop(string task)
{
    int head = 0 ;
    string temp ;

    for (int i = 0; i < listlength; i++)
    {
        list[head + 1] = list[head] ;
        temp = task ;
        list[head] = temp ;
        temp = "" ;
    }
}

void insertbottom(string task)
{
    int tail = listlength ;
    string temp ;

    for (int i = 0; i < listlength; i++)
    {
        list[tail - 1] = list[tail] ;
        temp = task ;
        list[tail] = temp ;
        temp = "" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use: `std::vector<std::string>` ? Saves you all the hassle.

Comment: i'm limeted to the header files i can use. i would have done this whole thing with vectors otherwise

Comment: @AlokSave: seems like this is an assignment about implementing those things yourself. otherwise a `std::priority_queue` would be probably better

Comment: @tarantino: how are `list` and `listlength` declared?

Comment: list is a string array and list length is the size of the array declared as an integer

Comment: @tarantino: can you show the complete code, including main() and all declaration/definitions? anyway apart from that there are a few problems with the algorithm i'm afraid

Comment: @AndyProwl http://pastebin.com/KSrh8WWx that's the whole code

Comment: Both `inserttop` and `insertbottom` are completely broken. For example, you are iterating over the index `i` but `i` is never used in the loop bodies, `temp` is being redundantly assigned and cleared over and over again, both `head` and `tail` are initialized but never updated, etc. It might help to get a piece of paper and simulate your code by hand to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the algorithm. I will take this function as a starting point:

```
void inserttop(string task)
{
    int head = 0 ;
    string temp ;

    for (int i = 0; i < listlength; i++)
    {
        list[head + 1] = list[head] ;
        temp = task ;
        list[head] = temp ;
        temp = "" ;
    }
}
```

First thing to notice, you cycle over different values of `i`, but you do not use `i` at all in your cycle. Secondly, you seem to add elements but never modify the length of your list (not sure how those variables are declared though, so I might make wrong assumptions here). Thirdly, the variable `temp` is useless here (especially, you do not need to reset it to the empty string at the end of each cycle).

It is likely that you meant something more similar to this:

```
void inserttop(string task)
{
    // Expand the list by one... [bounds check should be done, omitted here]
    listlength++;

    // Overwrite each element with the previous one, making room
    // for the new element in the first position of the array.
    // Take care of proceeding backwards (see the indexes used
    // inside the cycle) to avoid overwriting the first value
    // all over the list.
    for (int i = 1; i <= listlength; i++)
    {
        list[listlength - i] = list[listlength - i - 1] ;
    }

    // Now you can set the first element...
    list[0] = task;
}
```

And I believe `insertbottom` suffers from the same problem, so you will probably have to do something symmetrical:

```
// Again, don't forget to do bounds checking... this piece of code is just a hint
void insertbottom(string task)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listlength - 1; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1] ;
    }

    list[listlength] = task;

    listlength++;
}
```

Comment: would it be a case of just switching some operators from minus to plus please help my deadline is in 20 mins.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am glad to help if I see you want to learn, but I am not here to do your homework for free in a certain time limit, especially if you put no effort yourself

Comment: ok i seem to have got it but i keep overwriting the whole data it at the end and this leads to nothing gets displayed for the insertbottom() method

Comment: plus i understand your whole method of just not giving me the whole answer i won't learn anything that way

Comment: i have list[listlength - i] = list[listlength] ; in the for loop and list[listlength] = task; as setting the element

Comment: @tarantino: I updated my answer with some code for `insertbottom()`, but I haven't checked it. anyway, if it helps you at least improving your program, please consider upvoting my answer.